# "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'ashutoshmishra333@gmail.com'.",

Tags: django

while posting through postman getting error

> "Field 'id' expected a number but got '*********333@gmail.com'.",

## my view set

```
class PasswordViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

def create(self, request):
    try:
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        otp = request.data.get('otp')
        #user_obj = MyUser.objects.filter(email=email)
        otp_obj_check = Otp.objects.filter(email=email)
        user_obj=MyUser.objects.get(email=email)
        if not user_obj:
            raise Exception("email does not exist")
        if otp_obj_check:
            otp_obj = Otp.objects.filter(email=email).order_by('-id')[0]
        else:
            raise Exception("invalid otp")
        if not otp:
            raise Exception("please enter otp")
        if int(otp_obj.otp) == int(otp):
            for user_obj in user_obj:
                user_obj.set_password(password)
                user_obj.save()
                # token = get_access_token(user_obj)
        else:
            raise Exception('wrong otp')

        if not password:
            raise Exception('please enter password')


        return Response({"password": 'updated', "success": True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as error:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

## my model

```
class Otp(models.Model):

email=models.ForeignKey(MyUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
otp=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.otp
```

Answer (score 1):

Field *email* in model *Otp* referring the model *MyUser*. The primarykey field of *Myuser* is *id* (it is an integer).

so,

otp_obj_check = Otp.objects.filter(email=email) doesn't not filter by *email* field, it  filters by *id* field of Myuser.

To filter with *email* of *Myuser*, change your line 8 and 13 like below:

```
otp_obj_check = Otp.objects.filter(email__email=email)
```

and

```
otp_obj = Otp.objects.filter(email__email=email).order_by('-id')[0]
```

important double underscore between email and email

it filter based on *email* of *Myuser*.

I hope you have *email* field in *Myuser* model.